# user id not take over by jForm

Tags: joomla-5.x

I am writing my first extension (com_bnc) in Joomla and I want to save an existing user id and a date to a new table in the joomla database.

I did the following things:

I created a Controller which only extends the FormController LicenseController.php

```
class LicenseController extends FormController
{
    
}
```

I created a Model LicenseModel.php

```
namespace Bumblebee\Component\BNC\Administrator\Model;
\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\AdminModel;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;

class LicenseModel extends AdminModel
{
    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
    {
        $form = $this->loadForm(
            'com_bnc.license',
            'license',
            array(
                'control' => 'jform',
                'load_data' => $loadData
            ));
        if(empty($form))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return $form;
    }

    protected function loadFormData()
    {
        $app = Factory::getApplication();
        $data = $app->getUserState('com_bnc.edit.license.data',array());

        if(empty($data))
        {
            $data = $this->getItem();
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function getTable($name = '', $prefix = '', $options = array())
    {
        $name = 'Licenses';
        $prefix = 'Table';

        if($table = $this->_createTable($name, $prefix, $options))
        {
            return $table;
        }
        throw new \Exception(Text::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_TABLE_NAME_NOT_SUPPORTED', $name), 0);
    }

}
```

Created a table LicensesTable.php:

```
namespace Bumblebee\Component\BNC\Administrator\Table;
\defined('_JEXEC') or die;
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver;

class LicensesTable extends Table
{
    public function __construct(DatabaseDriver $db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__nc_license','UserID',$db);
    }
}
```

I created a template/layout edit.php:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

HTMLHelper::_('behavior.formvalidator');
HTMLHelper::_('behavior.keepalive');
?>

<form action="<?php echo Route::_('index.php?option=com_bnc&view=license&layout=edit&UserID=' . (int) $this->item->UserID); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="license-form" class="form-validate">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('UserID'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('valid_until'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="">
    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

I created a form license.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<form>
    <field
        name="UserID"
        type="user"
        label="COM_BNC_LICENSE_USERID"
        required="true"
        filter="unset"
    />
    <field
        name="valid_until"
        type="calendar"
        label="COM_BNC_LICENSE_VALID_UNTIL"
        required="true"
    />
</form>
```

The behavior is that I can trigger the form to add a new record (new Button) or load an existing record to edit. I see the UserID field as drop-down menu with all registered users and I can pick one. I can modify the date but when I hit the Save button or Save & Close button then I get the error message Field required: UserID.
No record will be written to the database.

In the debugger I see the following form data

```
Query String:
option: com_bnc
view: license
layout: edit
UserID: 364

Form Data
jform[UserID]: 364
jform[valid_until]: 2024-06-30
task: license.apply
```

I hope that this is not a silly question, but I try to find the error for some days now, without any success.... - Any pointer to resolve this error would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gerald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be in your `getTable` function in your model.

In Joomla 4 the meaning of the `$prefix` changed, so that now it should be set to 'administrator'. Also you shouldn't ever be calling the model `_createTable` function.

My recommendation would be to change your LicensesTable to LicenseTable, which means that it would be instantiated automatically by the MVC Factory class. Some documentation on this at https://manual.joomla.org/docs/building-extensions/components/mvc/mvc-overview

I think you should then be able to remove your `getTable` function completely from your model, as it will automatically pick the LicenseTable.

By the way, regarding the code:

```
HTMLHelper::_('behavior.formvalidator');
HTMLHelper::_('behavior.keepalive');
```

From Joomla 4 the 'behavior' things are no longer available.

Instead for the formvalidator use in your tmpl file:

```
$this->document->getWebAssetManager()->useScript('form.validate');
```

I don't think you need to specifically include keepalive - I think it's activated by default.

Comment: Thanks Robbie - I made your suggested modification and it improved the situation. - The "edit button" is now working and I can store an update of the date from the form with selected UserID to the database.
The "new button" kind of works better as well. It creates a new record in the database with the date from the form, but for the UserID it stores 0 to the database instead of the id of the selected user.

Comment: Looking again I see you've got filter="unset" in your license.xml file. This will remove the value (see libraries/src/Form/Filter/UnsetFilter.php). I suggest you try changing this to filter="int"

Comment: Thanks again for your response. - I modified the filter to "int" in the license.xml file but it seems somewhere else the UserID get set to 0. I checked with the Dev Tool and see the correct UserID in the form field right after clicking the "submit button". I further modifed the type from "user" to "number" and the strange thing is that it also set the UserID to 0 with this setting. - So I assume I amde somewhere else a mistake.

Comment: Could you add to your post your .sql file which you use to create your database table? Also if you zip up your component and put it on google drive or somewhere that I can download it from, then I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Robbie - finally I found my error .. it was within the table definition in the database ... now everything is working :) - Thank you so much for your help ...

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted. All the best with your Joomla coding!